# Playing games over different profiles

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-network

a- I downloaded GTA V game from UK account profile, and it's working normally
b- I tried to start it on another profile registered on US account and it's getting me error (Xbox store, can't open the game) 
notes:
all this happening at the same XBOX console
I work on XBOX 360

Answer (score 1):

The digitally purchased games are associated to a single Xbox Live profile.

Answer (score 1):

When you purchase a game on the Xbox 360 Marketplace, you get two licenses for playing the game:

- The first one is connected to your gamertag (profile), and allows you to always play the games you buy, on any console, as long as you are signed into that gamertag.
- The second license is connected to the Xbox 360 console you purchased the game on, and allows everyone on that console to play the game, with any gamertag.

If that is the case here, you can transfer your license from the other console to the one you're both playing on (you don't need the other console) by following [these instructions](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/store/download-content#89a94a78e73e42e1a9722a2ed5b73560).